# How to correctly allocate memory for an array of char pointers (strings of different length)?

Tags: arrays, c, memory-management, char

Sorry if it sounds like a duplicate, but I have checked similar questions and to my eye my approach is correct, therefore I would like to ask you for advice.

I want to allocate the memory for an array of pointers to the first elements of char arrays (in other words: this is an array of strings). Additionally, these strings may differ in length. I use realloc() for specific char arrays in order not to allocate unnecessary memory.

Here I present the fragments of the code that seem to be troublesome for me:

```
#define NUM_SEQ 4
#define MIN_BUFFER 1000
#define MAX_BUFFER 10000

char**  read_the_file(char* file_name) {
//opens the file

char** sequences = malloc(NUM_SEQ*sizeof(char*));
printf("all: %ld\n", sizeof(sequences)); //OUTPUT: 8
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SEQ; i++) {
    sequences[i] = malloc(MIN_BUFFER);
    printf("seq %d: %ld\n", i, sizeof(sequences[i]));  //OUTPUT: 8, for each of them
}

int num_of_seq = 0; //Number of the sequence in the array of sequences
int counter = 0; //Indicates the position of the character in the string
//Loop irrelevant to the problem is omitted
if (counter == sizeof(sequences[num_of_seq])) {
            printf("%ld\n", sizeof(sequences[num_of_seq]));
            printf("Here\n"); 
            if (sizeof(sequences[num_of_seq])*2 < MAX_BUFFER) {
                char* temp = realloc(sequences[num_of_seq], sizeof(sequences[num_of_seq])*2);
                if (temp != NULL) {
                    sequences[num_of_seq] = temp;
                } else {
                    printf("Allocating memory failure\n");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
            } else {
                printf("The sequence is too long\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
}
//Let this loop die in loneliness
return sequences;
}
```

Reallocating of the memory is a recent modification. Without it (simply allocating with malloc) the program works fine, even under valgrind. Now the results are correct, but the valgrind returns multiply times an error:

```
Address 0x4a5b810 is 0 bytes after a block of size 16 alloc'd
```

in various functions and always refer to this realloc

Another issue: the sequences don't exceed the length of 10. The counter shouldn't be equal to the size of the array, but the loop with realloc IS entered - which shouldn't have happened.

Sorry for terrible indentation, I have a problem with keeping the text in code style on this site and thank you for your much appreciated suggestions.

Comment: You cannot use `sizeof` to determine the size of allocated buffer. You should maintain the size separately.

Comment: Thank you, that's a good clue. However, could you tell me then what is displayed in output? The size of a pointer?

Comment: Yes, `sizeof` is for obtaining the size of type or expression passed. If you pass a pointer, you will get the size of the pointer.

Comment: Funny, Aside: why did you code with `ld` and `sizeof(sequences)`?,  Why not `"%lu"`, `"%d"`, `"%zd"`, `"%zu"`, `"%lld"`, etc?  What suggested `"%ld"`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, sizeof() doesn't return "simple" integers, but *unsigned* numbers - integers or longs, depends on a compiler. The size of a given structure cannot be negative, therefore we use unsigned. Additionally, size_t is used by i.e. malloc.

What has suggested "%ld"? Simply - the compiler ;)

Comment: Funny, "What has suggested "%ld"? Simply - the compiler" - this I doubt.   I will gladly apply more reputation toward you if you can report the compiler suggestion that implied `"%ld"`.  Far more likely the compiler reported something that indicated using `"%lu"`.  In any case, `"%zu"` is the _best_ print specify to use with `sizeof()`.  I just wanted to find out what was leading one astray.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, what do you mean by: "if you can report the compiler suggestion that implied *%ld*."? The compiler indicates that sizeof() returns *long unsigned int* in my case - I don't know, whether this fully answers your question. However, your insight on data types is an interesting and helpful remark.

Comment: Funny, "sizeof() returns long unsigned int in my case" --> that is expected (and does answer my Q.).  Why did you then use the _signed_ specifier  `"%ld"` which matches `long signed int` instead of `"%lu"` which matches `long unsigned int` as in the compiler suggestion?

Comment: I've changed the code again (`printf("%d", sequence[i])`) in order to see the output. The compiler underlines *sizeof(sth)* with a comment: *long unsigned int* and simultaneously underlines "%d" with a comment: *%ld*. It suggests *ld*, not *lu*.

Answer (score 1):

As @MikeCAT suggested, the issue was the improper use of sizeof(), which returns the size of the given expression or type. The solution to this problem is tracking the actual size of the object, i.e.: using the variable `actual_size_of_seq1`, initialized at `MIN_BUFFER` for the first sequence (I use an array of sizes, though).